# selenium get the value of an ajax with static id

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, phantomjs

I want to get the value of the option from from an ajax. The HTML code is:

```
<select id="j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:countryVal" name="j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:countryVal" size="1" onchange="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:searchlayout:mainform',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:j_id17','parameters':{'j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:j_id17':'j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:j_id17'} ,'status':'j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:statusProcess'} )" style="height:2.4em;width:65%;">   

<option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
```

as you can see, since id is available in the HMTL code, using the webdriverWait (below) does not help.

```
dropdownCountry = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    ((By.ID, "j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:countryVal")))
```

I tried

```
dropdownCountry = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:countryVal']/option")))
```

but it does not produce a list.

One option is use **time.sleep()**, to give the driver enough time to load the list of the countries. But I know it is not a good practice.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I think it isn't a bad practice

Comment: or use -> http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait until presence of `option` with **not empty** `value` attribute:

```
dropdownCountry = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
((By.ID, "j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:countryVal")))
dropdownCountry.click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id="j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:countryVal"]/option[not(@value='')]"))
list_of_options = [option.get_attribute('value') for option in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@id="j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:countryVal"]/option[not(@value='')]")]
```

Also you might need to wait until `option` with text content that is differs from `"Select Country"` appears:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id="j_id0:searchlayout:mainform:countryVal"]/option[not(text()='Select Country')]"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error: 

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:  {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"150","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:45065","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"sessionId\": \"b423c780-f2cd-11e6-8ec9-c1dae4070b7f\",

Comment: I guess this is because after `dropdownCountry.click()` the whole `select` element refreshed by `XHR`.. Check updated answer

Comment: no, I tried without .click(). The error is the same.

Comment: Ok. Let's make it clear... You get `StaleElementReferenceException` with my current code, right? Which line is cause this error?

Comment: it works now, there was a syntax error. Thanks for the help